# Building BorderPane with SplitPanes and minimize areas to hide nodes

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I am trying to build an BorderPane with SplitPanes to get a BorderPane which has resizeable areas by dragging the mouse. I have write some code which is working. But i cant hide the areas of the SplitPanes if there any nodes inside.

First of all i have build this stage and it works.

```
public class Example extends Application {

    StackPane gui;
    SplitPane splitVertical;
    SplitPane splitHorizontal;

    StackPane top;
    StackPane left;
    StackPane center;
    StackPane right;
    StackPane bottom;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        splitVertical = new SplitPane();
        splitVertical.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(0, 0.25);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(1, 0.75);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(2, 1.00);

        splitHorizontal = new SplitPane();
        splitHorizontal.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(0, 0.25);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(1, 0.75);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(2, 1.00);

        top = new StackPane();
        left = new StackPane();
        center = new StackPane();
        right = new StackPane();
        bottom = new StackPane();

        splitVertical.getItems().add(top);
        splitVertical.getItems().add(splitHorizontal);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(left);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(center);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(right);
        splitVertical.getItems().add(bottom);

        gui = new StackPane(splitVertical);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gui, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}
```

This code works fine. I have a "BorderPane" with all areas.

[image]

And i can resize the areas like i want and hide them completely, if i want.

[image]

But if there any nodes inside the areas, i cant hide the areas. I just can minimize them until the node is accepts. Here is an example.

```
public class Example extends Application {

    StackPane gui;
    SplitPane splitVertical;
    SplitPane splitHorizontal;

    StackPane top;
    StackPane left;
    StackPane center;
    StackPane right;
    StackPane bottom;

    Button buttonTop;
    Button buttonLeft;
    Button buttonCenter;
    Button buttonRight;
    Button buttonBottom;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        splitVertical = new SplitPane();
        splitVertical.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(0, 0.25);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(1, 0.75);
        splitVertical.setDividerPosition(2, 1.00);

        splitHorizontal = new SplitPane();
        splitHorizontal.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(0, 0.25);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(1, 0.75);
        splitHorizontal.setDividerPosition(2, 1.00);

        buttonTop = new Button("Top");
        buttonLeft = new Button("Left");
        buttonCenter = new Button("Center");
        buttonRight = new Button("Right");
        buttonBottom = new Button("Bottom");

        top = new StackPane(buttonTop);
        left = new StackPane(buttonLeft);
        center = new StackPane(buttonCenter);
        right = new StackPane(buttonRight);
        bottom = new StackPane(buttonBottom);

        splitVertical.getItems().add(top);
        splitVertical.getItems().add(splitHorizontal);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(left);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(center);
        splitHorizontal.getItems().add(right);
        splitVertical.getItems().add(bottom);

        gui = new StackPane(splitVertical);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gui, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I got a BorderPane.

[image]

But i cant hide the areas completely.

[image]

Is it possible to change the size of the areas until they are completely hide?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. The minSize of the childnode has set to 0. Then everything works fine.

```
buttonTop.setMinSize(0, 0);
buttonLeft.setMinSize(0, 0);
buttonCenter.setMinSize(0, 0);
buttonRight.setMinSize(0, 0);
buttonBottom.setMinSize(0, 0);
```